# Efficiently get hash entry only if it exists in Perl

Tags: perl, hashtable, exists, autovivification

I am quite often writing fragments of code like this:

```
if (exists $myHash->{$key}) {
    $value = $myHash->{$key};
}
```

What I am trying to do is get the value from the hash if the hash has that key in it, and at the same time I want to avoid autovivifying the hash entry if it did not already exist.

However it strikes me that this is quite inefficient: I am doing a hash lookup to find out if a key exists, and then if it did exist I am doing another hash lookup of the same key to extract it.

It gets even more inefficient in a multilevel structure:

```
if (exists $myHash->{$key1} 
    && exists $myHash->{$key1}{$key2} 
    && exists $myHash->{$key1}{$key2}{$key3}) {

    $value = $myHash->{$key1}{$key2}{$key3};
}
```

Here I am presumably doing 9 hash lookups instead of 3!

Is perl smart enough to optimize this kind of case? Or is there some other idiom to get the value of a hash without either autovivifying the entry or doing two successive lookups?

I am aware of the [autovivification](https://metacpan.org/pod/autovivification) module, but if possible I am looking for a solution that does not require an XS module to be installed. Also I have not had a chance to try this module out and I am not completely sure what happens in the case of a multilevel hash - the pod says that this:

```
$h->{$key}
```

would return undef if the key did not exist - does that mean that this:

```
$h->{$key1}{$key2}
```

would die if $key1 did not exist, on the grounds that I am trying to de-reference undef? If so, to avoid that presumably you would still need to do multi-level tests for existence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about optimization since hash lookups are fast. But for your first case, you can do:

```
if (my $v = $hash{$key}) {
    print "have $key => $v\n";
}
```

Similarly:

```
if ( ($v = $hash{key1}) && ($v = $v->{key2}) ) { 
    print "Got $v\n";
}
```

Comment: That's surprising - I had thought that any lvalue use of a non-existent hash entry would add the key to the hash (with value undef in this case). Clearly I am wrong. Amazing I did not pick that up after years of writing perl code!

Comment: autovivification only happens in nested accesses

Comment: @harmic, yes, if the hash entry is an lvalue, it will be autovivified, but you may be misunderstanding the meaning of lvalue. In this case the hash is on the right-hand side of the assignment; this makes it an rvalue, not an lvalue. Autovivification of rvalue hash entries, as @perreal says, only happens with nested accesses - e.g. `$h->{foo}{bar}{baz}` will automatically do something like `$h->{foo}{bar} //= {}`.

Comment: @tobyink oops sorry, that was a typo, I meant rvalue

Comment: @perreal: this way you're not testing if the hash element _exists_, as the OP requested, you're testing if `$hash{$key}` is _true_, which is a different (stricter) test of course.

Answer (score 2):

Autovivification doesn't happen for single-level access so you can safely write

```
my $value = $hash{$key};
```

For multi-level access intermediate entries will be autovivified. e.g.

```
my $value = $hash{a}{b};
```

will create a reference to an empty hash if `$hash{a}` doesn't already exist. (If it does exist and isn't a hash reference, perl will throw an error and die.) To avoid that, you need to check each level first. You can write a subroutine to check existence of arbitrarily nested keys.

```
sub safe_exists {
    my $x = shift;
    foreach my $k (@_) {
        no warnings 'uninitialized';
        return unless ref $x eq ref {};
        return unless exists $x->{$k};
        $x = $x->{$k};
    }
    return 1;
}

if (safe_exists(\%hash, qw(a b))) {...}
```

Depending on your algorithm (and why you're trying to avoid autovivification) locking your hash can be a useful alternative to `no autovivification` or multi-layer `exists` tests.

```
use Hash::Util;

my %hash = (a => { b => 1 });
Hash::Util::lock_hash_recurse(%hash);

say $h{a}{b}; # 1
say $h{a}{c}; # error!
```

I mostly use this as a way to detect programming errors when working with complex data structures. It's useful for detecting mis-typed key names or inadvertent modification of values.